# Array of arrays, get first element and length. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is picture of my data I have:

[image: console.log]

Im trying to get array of objects, which will look like this:

```
[{
    length: 2,
    item: {
       imgSource: "/sushi/test2.png"
       ingredients: "Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame, Unagi sauce"
       name: "sushi1"
       price: 133
       weight: 120}
}, 

{   
    length: 1,
    item: {
       imgSource: "/sushi/test1.png"
       ingredients: "Salmon, Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese"
       name: "sushi2"
       price: 119
       weight: 120}
}]
```

The best way i think of is to use `reduce` function, but i have no idea how to use it right, can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the question/problem? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually:

```js
var items = [
   [{
      imgSource: "/sushi/test2.png",
      ingredients: "Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame, Unagi sauce",
      name: "sushi1",
      price: 133,
      weight: 120,
   }, {
      imgSource: "/sushi/test2.png",
      ingredients: "Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame, Unagi sauce",
      name: "sushi1",
      price: 133,
      weight: 120,
   }],

   [{
      imgSource: "/sushi/test1.png",
      ingredients: "Salmon, Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese",
      name: "sushi2",
      price: 119,
      weight: 120,
   }]
]

items = items.reduce(function(carry, item) {
    if (!carry.hasOwnProperty(item.name)) {
      carry.push({
        count: item.length,
        item: item[0]
      })
    }
    return carry;
}, [])

console.log(items)
```

Comment: How can you add an answer when there's no question or problem? o.O

Comment: The question is implicit. So much for the 'how'. But considering your 'why', you're right. I should have flagged this question. Sometimes, I'm eager to help and should pay more attention.

Comment: _"The question is implicit. So much for the 'how'"_ - The "blue i" tells a different story.

Comment: Which "blue i"? The one from the screenshot?

Comment: Yes. The logged array is changed later in time. Nothing in the "question" indicates such an asynchronous action. So this is not the whole story.

Comment: What about asking that in the comments below the question. That's something I can't give you an answer to.

Comment: Just don't answer unclear and zero-effort "questions". Especially nice to answer and then to close-vote. Oh sweet reputation...

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a loop through all items of your array
2. Compare objects of the current item and the result array ([How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects))
3. If the same item found -  inc the value "length" of that result array.
4. If it is not found - add a new item to the result array with the length = 1

Comment: Could you please provide an example?